# Use/Grab the only keyboard with no user logged locally

Tags: keyboard, tty, framebuffer

I have a raspberry pi running some software (I have the source) that needs user interaction and has a special (USB) keyboard with only 3 keys.
The program runs on framebuffer (SDL) and is launched remotely; I need this program to react to the key presses, but seems impossible if the user is not logged in locally.

What can I do? The solution must not use a lot of resources, and the delay should be within 300ms.

Typical use case is one key press every 10 minutes over the course of 4-8 hours, but can be as often as a key press every 2 seconds (highly unlikely). This all runs on top of raspbian, I have root access .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by reading the raw input device and parsing it similarly to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2554421/3530257

Answer (score 1):

Install openssh-server (on the RPi)

```
apt-get install openssh-server
```

You may want to use ssh with the `-X` switch (from another host)

```
ssh -X <username>@<IP_of_Rasperry_Pi>
[Enter password when prompted]
```

Once you're connected, your prompt should have changed to what you'd see when you're logged in locally on the raspberry pi.

After you're connected, run `epiphany &` to run the default web browser included with Raspbian and display it on the client machine (not the Raspberry Pi) and navigate to the website that runs the program in question, and open it.

You could attach a [normal] keyboard to the Pi, and Switch to Multi-User Mode (without graphics) by pressing `Ctrl + Alt + F1`, logging in as root and entering `pkill X` (yes, the X needs to be capitalized) at the tty to kill the GUI on the display directly connected to the pi (saves system resources). Then you can ssh into it (don't forget the `-X` option) and open the browser (like before). Or instead of attaching a keyboard you could also use ssh (without the `-X` switch) to kill the X server. One thing to note, this command will kill all X sessions running on the pi, including any you may establish with ssh.

This will only work if keys can be mapped to the program via the keyboard used on the remote connection.

To set the GUI to not appear on boot-up [locally on the RPi], use the `sudo raspi-config` command and follow the instructions given here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1320

I hope this helps solve your issue.